# iOS Push notification long press requirements

Tags: push-notification, push, long-integer

To add long press options to a push notification, what is required?
Does it require Rich notification?
How are the long press options controlled?

Haven’t tried yet, just setting up requirements for the team.

Suggested example would be wonderful.

Comment: https://medium.com/@lucasgoesvalle/custom-push-notification-with-image-and-interactions-on-ios-swift-4-ffdbde1f457